# Getting AttributeError: __enter__ when using Microphone from Speech Recognizer

Tags: python, speech-recognition

The code is below. As I researched the documention Speech_Recognision must be installed if we use Microphone. So I installed it but still i have this error.

```
def recordAudio():

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone as source:
    print('I am listening to you sir.')
    audio = r.listen(source)
    data = ''

try:
    data = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print('You said: ' + data)
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print('Voice cannot be recognized.')
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print('Req results:' + e)

return data
```

line 54, in recordAudio
    with sr.Microphone as source:
AttributeError: `__enter__`

Answer (score 3):

An `AttributeError: __enter__` means you are attempting to enter a context manager block with an object which does not support the context manager protocol; it does not have a `__enter__` method.

Specifically, you are attempting to open the `sr.Microphone` class in you `with` statement. As per the [documentation](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#microphonedevice_index-unionint-none--none-sample_rate-int--16000-chunk_size-int--1024---microphone), you need to provide an instance `sr.Microphone()` to the context manager instead.

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For all those who did not get solution to this problem:

Instead of using the class `sr.Microphone` as a source, use the object  `sr.Microphone()`.

Because we are supposed to call the method using the speechRecognition object and not the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

It would constantly listen until you terminate:
[SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def speech_recog():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    mic = sr.Microphone()
    while True:
        with mic as source:
            print("Speak...")

            audio = r.listen(source)

            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print(f"You said {text}")

            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("Didnt hear that try again")
speech_recog()
```